# Root domains on port 443 all redirect to vhost

Tags: apache, wamp

I have my vhost file set up as follows:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain1"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain1/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.domain1.com/
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain2"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain2/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain2.com\fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain2.com\privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.domain2.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain2"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain2/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain3.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain3"
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/domain3/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain3.com\fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain3.com\privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain3.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.domain3.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain3.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain3"
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/domain3/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain4.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain4"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain4/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain4.com\fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Certbot\live\www.domain4.com\privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain4.com
        Redirect permanent / http://www.domain4.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain4.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/domain4"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/domain4/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's a lot longer than that, but all other domains work fine. It's just the ones with ssl that don't work. I included one regular domain as well (domain1), which uses cloudflare's ssl for partial encryption.

Like in the example, I have 3 domains with actual proper ssl, because the websites require it for functionality (mediawiki and wp). For some reason, instead of domainx.com redirecting to [www.domainx.com](http://www.domainx.com), they all stay as domainx.com and display the page from domain2.

I'll give an example: when I go to domain1.com, it redirects to [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) and everything is fine. When I go to domain2.com, it displays the contents of itself but doesn't redirect to [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com). When I go to domain3.com, it displays the content of domain2.com, but when I go to [www.domain3.com](http://www.domain3.com) it works correctly. Idem for domain 4.

When I remove the port 443 vhosts and just have the domains as port 80, they work. Conversely, when I remove either the redirect rule or the port 80 virtualhost of a domain, it still displays the page from domain2 on the root domain. When I remove the domain2 vhost, it just displays the page of a different port 443 vhost. When there is just one page with actual ssl, I get a service unavailable error when I try to access just the root domain.

Can someone please help me solve this one? It's a real headscratcher.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: You may also benefit from reading through [this thread on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) because some of the thnigs you have done look rather odd

Comment: I'm using 3.3.0, and I don't see what's weird about the configuration of my vhosts file?